# VS 2017 Sign in Failed with error - Failed to get VSO Profile during account Creation because of 'System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Looks like VS 2017 is unable to fetch token.

Below is error log inside `%temp%\servicehub\logs`

```
09/28/2017 09:40:15 : Error : Problem Acquiring a token silenly for resource: '499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798', tenant:'f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a', User: 'Mna65znCLiotTD5qiArTl5rffTOhEPc5a2WFjqE2VTo' due to 'System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: accessToken
   at Microsoft.Requires.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AccessTokenResult..ctor(String accessToken, String tokenType, ErrorResult error)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.NetworkServicesImpl.<AcquireTokenSilentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()'
09/28/2017 09:42:03 : Error : Creating an account
IsPersonalization account 'False'
No scopes passed in, looking for scopes on the account.
Found  '0' scopes on the account
Checking if the account is an MSA account. 'True'
Setting properties.
Checking if we are windows platform to determine if we want to get the profile or not.
We are on the windows platform. Getting profile information.
Failed to get VSO Profile during account Creation because of 'System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: accessToken
   at Microsoft.Requires.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AccessTokenResult..ctor(String accessToken, String tokenType, ErrorResult error)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.NetworkServicesImpl.<AcquireTokenSilentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.NetworkServicesImpl.<GetProfileInfoAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AadAccountProviderService.<CreateAccountFromAadAsync>d__27.MoveNext()'
Getting tenant and scope info.
Setting more properties.
Checking if the id token is null or empty.
Id Token found. Parsing the token.
Getting the images
Instantiating the new account.
Returning the new account.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled `WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service` and everything was back on track!